# Manipulating a copied attr

Tags: jquery, variables, string, attr

I'm working on a simple lightbox script for my website, that wraps a link (A) around a image. The link URL should then be the SRC of the image, but slightly manipulated.

The image URL could look like this: "pb028855_copy_147x110.jpg" and I want it to delete "*147x110", from after "copy*" to before ".jpg" that is.

My current script, to copy the SRC from the image to the link is like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('img.withCaption').each(function(){
        var $imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).wrap('<a rel="lightBox" />');
        $(this).parent().attr("href", ""+$imgSrc);
    });
});
```

How can I use parts of a attr?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not certain exactly what the numbers will be, you could use the [`replace()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method  with a regular expression.

```
$(function(){
    $('img.withCaption').each(function(){
        var $imgSrc = this.src.replace(/_\d+x\d+\./,'.');
        $(this).wrap('<a rel="lightBox" />')
               .parent().attr("href", ""+$imgSrc);
    });
});
```

So this:

```
pb028855_copy_147x110.jpg
```

will end up as this:

```
pb028855_copy.jpg
```

Comment: Nice response, more in depth than mine +1.

Answer (score 0):

They are several ways of manipulating strings, depends of what you exactly want, for example:

```
$imgSrc = $imgSrc.replace(/thumb/, 'big');
```

Answer (score 0):

The attr method simply returns a string, you can manipulate it just like any other one. So a regex replace would work.

```
$(function(){
    $('img.withCaption').each(function(){
        var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src")*.replace(/_copy_\d+x\d+\.jpg$/, "_copy.jpg")*;
        $(this).wrap($('<a rel="lightBox" />').attr("href", imgSrc);
    });
});
```

(I cleaned up the wrapping part a bit.)